# Can someone help check my solution for this timing diagram?

Tags: digital-logic, clock, flipflop, timing, counter

I've been working on some timing diagrams and I keep mixing up the behaviors for the different flip flops.

---

**EDIT:**

I think I have the logic correct. If someone could please let me know if I'm anywhere close, I'd greatly appreciate it! Here's what I believe is how Y2, Y3, and Y4 should behave.

If anyone can let me know if I'm close, it'd make my day! Thanks.

Black is what was given and red is what I've done so far.

[image: My predicted solution]

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework exercise. You should really try to show what you've done so far. The way you put it out there it looks like "gimee the answer".

Comment: I've been working on it. Each time I trace it and keep track of the values, I get a different answer. I don't understand how to determine when the values change, where they change, and why. I seriously have gotten 7 or 8 different solutions. I'll update it in a moment, sorry.

Comment: Then you may want to look online at one of the 100's of data sheets for flip-flops and latches. These almost always show a timing diagram that explains the particular part. Look up data sheets for 74HC74 and 74HC112 for starting points.

Comment: This problem looks like it's testing if you know how various flip-flops work. Essentially, for clocked flip flops, the output of the flip flop will only change on a rising or falling clock edge, so you only ever care about the clock edges. Which edge you care about, and what the input is in relation to the output, is based on the flip flop type and is what they're testing here.

Comment: Here's an example from wilipedia for a JK flip flop. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:JK_timing_diagram.svg

Comment: @StaceyAnne thank you. I've updated the diagram. Everything in black was given, and my attempt is in red. When the clock and x are both 1 on the rising edge, Y1 flips? Is this close?

Comment: No. The edges of X (the T input for Y1) do not matter.  The T input is not edge-triggered, only the clock. The **level** of the T input matters at the **time** that the clock is jumping from 0 to 1. The clock tells the flip-flop when to sample the T input. When it's not being sampled, the input doesn't matter.

Comment: If both T and the clock change state at the same time, that is a bad thing: it is a setup/hold time violation. Your homework problem carefully avoids this. Note how X and CLOCK never change at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are almost there, except that you are mixing up the behavior of the T input and the clock.

The way you have solved for the T flip flop looks like you believe that the high values of the clock specify "toggle requested" and the rising edge of the T input actually triggers the toggle.

But in fact it is exactly the other way around! A high value of the T input specifies a request to the flip-flop that "a toggle is requested", and the rising edge of the clock is the trigger. If T is high, while a clock edge arrives, then the flip-flop toggles. If T is low while the edge arrives, nothing happens.

It looks like you understand the concept, but you mixed up the roles of the signals.

Comment: so instead of basing the time of Y1 on X, I should use clk? Like do what I did already, but use clk?

Comment: Yes, base the **time** on the **clk**!

Comment: ok awesome thanks! I updated it. Could you possibly check if I changed it correctly?

Comment: Yes. I think you almost have it. The only problem is that the first toggle does not happen. Why? Because the T input is zero while the clock rises. T goes high shortly after the clock rises, but it's too late already. It has missed the edge.

Comment: It's like sports. X lays the groundwork and assists, but CLOCK scores the goal. :)

Comment: **Now here is something advanced to think about.** In real-world digital timing (and hence real timing diagrams), events are not instantaneous. A flip flop does not change state **immediately** upon the clock edge, but some small time afterward. There are propagation delays through the circuits.  Furthermore, there are timing **constraints**. In order for the T signal to be correctly processed upon the rising edge of the clock, it has to be present slightly before the clock arrives, and also has to stay in place slightly after. These two times are called "setup time" and "hold time".

Comment: Oh wow. Yeah dealing with fractions of nano seconds must be miserable!

Comment: In other words, suppose you had given signals in which the T input rises at exactly the same time as the clock. That situation is indeterminate! The T signal has violated the constraint on setup time, so there is no guarantee that it will be properly registered. Your homework problem carefully avoids asking you this! The X signal is carefully skewed so that the changes do not coincide with clock edges.

Comment: Careful now, you may have over-compensated in your last change! On the second rising of the clock, T is high! But your flip-flop is flatlining ... no toggle, oops.

Comment: Ok thanks again! I think I have it correct now?

Comment: I updated my question to reflect what I believe the rest of the timing diagram should do. I'd like your feedback once more if you don't mind lol.

Comment: Y2 has a level-triggered clock input, so basically it acts like a valve. When the clock is high, the D flip-flop follows what the input is doing, but when the clock is low, the flip flop ignores the input.  About Y3, you are wrong because the flip flop does not *toggle* since it is a D flip flop, not a T flip flop! On the clock edge, it simply accepts the input and stores it. Y4 is triggered on the negative edge and its a JK flip flop: you should study those in detail.

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#JK_flip-flop   When you tie the inputs of the JK flip flop together, you basically get a toggling flip flop like a T.  But of course, this one is negative edge triggered so you cannot just copy the diagram from Y1.

Comment: Ok thanks! I updated it again. It has to be close - if not - correct now I feel like

Comment: @Kaz: In the absence of any sort of specified time scale for the timing diagram, I tend to assume "long" [e.g. one second per pixel].  If the time scale is short relative to logic propagation times, the appearance of the diagram would change markedly, but it would probably look the same with a timescale of a millisecond per pixel or an hour per pixel.