# What makes these simple circuit diagrams different?

Tags: clock, flipflop, latch

I'm kind of confused with the behavior changes of these 3 differences of a flip flop.

I made an image to easily show what I'm asking about. I circled the differences in red.. Heres the image:

[image: whats the difference?]

For 3.) I believe that it just inverts the value going in?

I'm not really sure about the differences in the first two though.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two are the same, and denote a flip-flop that changes state on the rising edge of the clock. The third one denotes a FF that changes on the falling edge of the clock.

Comment: Ok so the "clk" and ">" mean the same thing?

Comment: @DaveTweed, you're absolutely sure the 2nd one isn't some professor's symbol for a D-latch? I've never seen that symbol before, so AFAIK it could stand for just about anything, depending on the context it's used in.

Comment: @ThePhoton: I have no context, so I'm just giving the most obvious interpretation of the symbol, based on my experience. Of course, anything is possible. Normally, the control input of a D latch would be called "enable", not "clock".

Comment: @ThePhoton I asked another question that's more specific. And this is what was given: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65093/can-someone-help-me-understand-how-to-make-a-timing-diagram?rq=1

Comment: @DaveTweed yeah we use both. But I can't remember for the 1st and 2nd examples in this image

Comment: @DaveTweed, I think "Enable" is a better name too, but I just did a Google image search for "D-latch" and the majority of results seem to use `C` or `CLK` for that pin and only a few use `E` or `EN` or `Enable`.

Comment: @Ted, you need to check your textbook or lecture notes and see what conventions they are using for different devices.

Comment: Given the context of @Ted's other question, it seems likely that the professor intended that the two devices in the middle would have different, rather than identical behavior ... so you may be right in this case. But it's quite ambiguous, and should have been clearly stated as part of the question.

Comment: @DaveTweed so essentially they are the same - in the case of my other question?

Answer (score 5):

The convention is that > is edge triggered and clk by itself is level triggered.

Bubble > is negative edge triggered, Bubble by itself is negative level triggered.

An example of a level triggered FF is a a SR latch preceded by the S and R being gated with the clock signal with AND gates.